# System console encoding format problem?

Tags: command-line, encoding

I'm using blender 2.82 on windows.The default blender system console is cmd.exe and it doesn't support Unicode so the non-ascii characters be garbled. Here's my question:

1.can i replace the default console with other terminal like cmder?
2.or can i set the system encoding format to utf-8?

Comment: Off topic. The question is in regard to setting the encoding format of the windows OS system console.   I am not on windows to test (btw windows is only OS that has the show system console menu entry, on any OS Blender can be started from a console via the command line.)  see if setting another as default https://superuser.com/questions/509642/how-to-change-the-default-terminal-emulator-on-windows-cmd does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [cmder](https://conemu.github.io/) based on [conemu](https://conemu.github.io/), you can set it as default terminal through `Settings > Integration > Default term`

Before launching Blender you need to change code page to utf-8 by [command](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) `chcp 65001`

[image: conemu screenshot]

Comment: Thank you this is worked.